# Integration between GitLab.com (Code) and Hosted GitLab server (Wiki/Issues/CI/CD)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, issue-tracking

I have a business use-case from a startup to maintain all code repositories on GitLab.com SaaS. And all other services like Wiki, Issue Tracking, CI/CD on a Self-managed/Hosted GitLab.

I could not find any references or examples of such scenario. Is this kind of integration possible. Any references or links would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, but there are a number of steps you have to take to get it set up.

1. As an admin on your self-hosted Gitlab installation, go into the Admin area, then Settings, then General, and expand *Visibility and Access Controls*. Then under *Import Sources* select all the sources you want to allow your users to import projects from. For this use case, make sure you select at least *Gitlab.com*.
2. Next you have to integrate your self-hosted Gitlab instance with Gitlab.com by following the instructions [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/gitlab.html).
3. Once all of this is done, go to the *Projects* page in your self-hosted Gitlab, and hit the green *New Project* button. You should see three tabs across the top of the New Project page, with the one on the right called *Import Project*. Click that tab, hit the button for Gitlab.com, and follow the instructions on the page.

Once all that is done, your developers can do all the source control activites on gitlab.com, and all changes will be synced to your self-hosted gitlab for issues, wiki's, and CI/CD.